# Rails Discard gem - before_discard, custom error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a blog. I have Articles with Posts. Instead of destroying, I want to base on discarding everything.
I expect that you need to archive all posts before archiving the article. When this condition is not met, I want to get an error 404 and then use it as JSON in my view.
I am currently getting error 500 with the default message: "Request failed with status code 500" and in backend only: `Discard::RecordNotDiscarded (Failed to discard the record)`.

Here is my article model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  include Discard::Model
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true
  before_discard :can_destroy?, prepend: true

  def can_destroy?
    if posts.kept.any?
      errors.add(:base, "First you have to archive all posts in this article")
      throw :abort
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get an error 404

404 is usually used when the record is not found, in your scenerio it exists so I suggest returning 422 (unprocessable entity) instead.

And to answer your original question - there are few options possible.

1. Check if `posts.kept.any?` before calling `discard`.
2. Use `catch` to handle the `throw` that you implemented.
3. Raise an exception instead of using `throw` and rescue it.